# CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: never getting called

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to list my Bluetooth headphones in my iOS application and connect them progmatically from my application in order to listen music from my application.

using this code

```
centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
```

But I'm not able to connect as my delegate method is never getting called?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are discovering the headphones, can you show more of the code where you connect; Are you saving the `peripheral` in a property?

Comment: I'm not able to list headphones basically but nearer available devices. And i want to list the Bluetooth headphones. No luck

Answer (score 0):

Most Bluetooth headphones will not advertise a BLE service, they will simply use a legacy handsfree or headset audio profile.  This means that they will not be visible to an app using Core Bluetooth.

Even headphones that do have a BLE service will typically use a proprietary service that is just for tasks like configuration and firmware updates.

Bluetooth audio devices are handled through [`AVAudioSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession) - See the section on *Working with Audio Routes*

Comment: How through AVAudioSession i will be able to connect Headphones with app? can you please brief some more details.

Comment: See [`AVRoutePickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your issue, but ...

This can happen if you don't hold a reference to the peripheral after the connection.

Wherever you are connecting, make sure to keep a reference to the actual `CBPeripheral` until the connection fails or connects.

Otherwise you'll likely see this:

```
 API MISUSE: Cancelling connection for unused peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x2825a89c0, identifier = 58ABFF83-C13F-357A-3C1D-06EA99C584A6, name = xxxx, mtu = 0, state = connecting>, Did you forget to keep a reference to it?
```